# ensure user can only be logged in on one computer at a time?

Tags: customization, security

how can i make sure a user can only be logged in on one computer at a time? I want to make a wordpress site that could potentially have paid accounts for content in the future. Is there anything built into wordpress that prevents a user from being logged in more than once?

Comment: do you mean that the user can't use multiple browsers? multiple windows/tabs of the same browser?

Comment: hmmm. Ya know I'm not sure. For the moment I was just thinking multiple computers. I don't want multiple people to be able to use the same account at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way could be hooking into the login process and check if the user is already logged.

There is a 'wp_authenticate' action that runs just before loggin in an user.

Comment: any chance you could give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

You would be shocked and amazed at how difficult this is to do properly.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/prevent-multiple-login-using-a-single-id?replies=3

Answer (score 0):

Some of the paid subscription plugins offer this. One that I know of off hand and had good experience with is

[Your Members](http://www.yourmembers.co.uk/the-plugin/) with [additional addon](http://www.yourmembers.co.uk/the-plugin/addon/your-minder/)

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to @Daniel Dvorkin Answer: I guess you could "simply" hook two functions. One that is fired on login and another one triggered on logout. In both cases you could add some user meta data: logged in/out. If someone is checked in and checks in another time, you will already know in your login action.